# How to appropriately test if a generic type extends another generic type

Tags: typescript

Given a generic type:

```js
type Bar<T> = { a: T }
type Bar1 = Bar<'a string'> extends Bar<string> ? 'As Expected' : 'Surprising' // 'As Expected'
```

As `'a string' extends string`, I naturally assumed `Bar<'a string'> extends Bar<string>`.
However, due to covariance and contravariance, it doesn't always work as I assumed:

```js
type Foo<T> = (a: T) => T
type Foo1 = Foo<'a string'> extends Foo<string> ? 'As Expected' : 'Surprising' // 'Surprising'
```

One solution is to write one's own `extends` function by doing something like this

```js
// A workaround
type Foo2 = Foo<'a string'> extends Foo<infer Inner>
  ? Inner extends string
    ? 'As Expected'
    : 'Surprising'
  : 'Surprising' // 'As Expected'
```

However, this quickly becomes a nightmare if one is creating composite types with many generics.

Another solution (and the one I currently use) is to reduce the extends checking:

```js
type FooBase = (a: any) => any
type Foo3 = Foo<'a string'> extends FooBase ? 'As Expected' : 'Surprising' // 'As Expected'
```

Has anyone else run into this problem and found any better or other solutions than the ones I have?

Comment: Are you asking how to compare the generic type parameter without any regard to how that type parameter is actually used? This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Whatever your goal is, I think there's most likely a better way.

Comment: You make an assumption. You find that your assumption is wrong. You know the reason why your assumption is wrong. Then suddenly out of nowhere you want to come up with a "solution". What is this solution trying to "solve"? There is no problem here.

Comment: @Ricky Mo - I'm using generic types as generics and I want to require that those generics extend a specific generic type.  The best solution I've found is not to do so and I was wondering if someone else had a better solution.